# 502 proxy error, Oracle VM + Hortonworks sandbox

Tags: apache, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am new to Hadoop. Oracle VM with Hortonworks sandbox (OS Red Hat 64bit) with HDP 2.3.2 is up and running. When i am trying to test via `http://192.168.56.101` i get the 502 proxy error.

`Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /.
Reason: Error reading from remote server`

I have done the same installation and configuration on both my pc and mac and i get the same error. I have tried the test from IE and chrome as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also got same issue when I try it in another browser it worked, so you can try in different browser.  And also increase your VMware allocated memory for hortonworks VM.

Comment: I doubled the memory from 8GB to 16GB, and tried both FF and Chrome, still no luck here

Answer (score 1):

Click on machine tab of Horton sandbox virtual box running instance and click Reset. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. It resolved the 502 error .

Answer (score 0):

Usually it happens when the *Ambari* is restarting or shutting down. Just wait for a few seconds and it should resolve.

You can also try to open it in `incognito` mode or clear the cookies.

To clear the cookies, for the chrome browser:

1. Click on `i` icon which is at the left side of URL
2. Click on `Cookies`
3. Remove all cookies one-by-one

It should solve.

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work here for both 8080 and 8888

Comment: Basically what happens is when we start _ambari_, although it says _started_ in the virtual box, it takes a few minutes to start in the background. This boot time depends upon the resources available in the system. Just wait for a few minutes and check if it starts.

Comment: waited for a whole night and still won't start, there is something else wrong

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, I have assigned about 8.5 GB of ram to virtual machine. I was thinking its ram issue. But later, I found that it takes a couple of minutes to start its internal service after you start your virtual machine, depending on your system specifications.

So start the virtual machine and wait a couple of minutes after you see the URL printed on the screen.